# Mongodb - Modelling a product catalog with user specific pricing

Tags: mongodb

Looking at the mongoDB product catalog example (for data caching lookups), how would I best implement pricing and qty available that is specific to the user logged in. 
I am picturing a layout something like this:

```
[{"_id":"skuA",
  "details":{ "msrp": "$15", "short_desc": "my short description"}
, "PriceQty" : [{"custid": 1, "price":10 , "qty":25 },{"custid": 2, "price":9 , "qty":20 }]
}]
```

(but i would need to push in updated (or add if first log in) pricing when the user logs in (ex: remove where custid = 1 from all documents and push in ).
Or 
Would it make sense to keep the item information in one place and create a separate collection holding the sku, price, customer, and qty? Not sure how I would use a reference ID on that to get an effectively SQL left join from the item collection to pricing collection with this second approach.

The Item collection would hold 100k+ (for quoting purposes) but the pricing and qty would hold 2k for what could be ordered on the spot. Unfortunately, I have my mind in the relational world still.

Comment: It's really hard to follow your question. FYI: There aren't joins in MongoDB.

Comment: I'm way to wordy. I want to store a large inventory collection once and store pricing information separately because price/qty is different for each customer and 95% of the inventory has a price of "call for quote". Since there are no joins in mongo, how do i best merge in the price collection when they search the inventory collection.

Comment: You can only return a collection of documents or a single document. You can't "merge" documents within MongoDB.